# What are 3 sins mentioned in Shivastotravalli?

Tags: shiva, sin, shivastotravali

[Shivatotravalli](https://archive.org/details/ShriSivaStotravaliSwamiLakshmanJoo) is one of the great work of Kashmiri Acharya Sri Utpaladeva. In [chapter 2 verse 3](https://archive.org/details/ShriSivaStotravaliSwamiLakshmanJoo/page/n31) he says:

> "O Paramatma Deva! Because of being full of bliss "balsamic", **because of destroying all 3 sins "Restful"**, and because of burning this worldly differences, your Indescribable well-being form "AgniSwarupa"; My salutations to your all these 3 forms!"

In the bold part of above verse, there is mentioning of 3 sins. What are these 3 sins?

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Could be interpretation of author then?

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Check the translation in the link I have hyperlinked in the question part.

Answer (score 5):

These are not sins.  They are tāpas. Literal meaning is heat. We can say they are type of pains experienced by us due to different reasons. They are three in number and are called **tāpatraya** meaning trio of tāpa. **The Hindi translation linked in the question also uses this terminology**.
It's a mistake made in translating Hindi to English.hey are:

1. ādhyātmika (bodily and mental pain).
2. ādhibhautika (natural but incidental pain)
3. ādhidaivika (superhuman)

First misery or pain is caused by our body or mind. It's internal factor. Example is stress and tension. Second is by other living beings externally. Harming a person by beating, bite by a dog etc., come under this category. Last misery is caused by super human entities like devatas, gandharvas, grahas etc.,

God is called as destroyer of these three miseries and give us relief. Lord Shiva is called Sheetala (who is cold) because it's the opposite of tāpa (heat).

For more information on Tāpatraya, see [wisdomlib.org](https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/tapatraya).

Answer (score 1):

[Sin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sin#Hinduism)  (Sanskrit: पाप pāpa "vice") describes actions that create negative karma by violating moral and ethical codes, which automatically brings negative consequences.

Sri Krishna says in Gita about 3 major emotions, which result in sin.

> ध्यायतो विषयान्पुंसः सङ्गस्तेषूपजायते।
>
> सङ्गात् संजायते कामः कामात्क्रोधोऽभिजायते।।2.62।।
>
> In the case of a person who dwells on objects, there arises attachment
>   for them. From **attachment** grows **hankering** (strong desire), from
>   hankering springs **anger**.
>
> क्रोधाद्भवति संमोहः संमोहात्स्मृतिविभ्रमः।
>
> स्मृतिभ्रंशाद् बुद्धिनाशो बुद्धिनाशात्प्रणश्यति।।2.63।।
>
> From anger follows delusion; from delusion, failure of memory; from
>   failure of memory, the loss of understanding; from the loss of
>   understanding, he perishes.

---

The root cause of all types of emotions, which give rise to negative actions, finally causing fall, is 3 major emotions- **attachment, desire and anger**/sins.

Meditation/reciting sacred mantra or name, etc, of Shiva, Vishnu, Shakti, etc, or on/of formless God, will eliminate these 3 sins.